# Error when building a next.js application

Tags: mongodb, next.js, build

When I do yarn build (next build) on my next.js application, I get the following error. When doing yarn dev, it works perfectly, but not when building. I've tried doing yarn cache clean --force, deleting the node_modules folder and doing yarn install, but it doesn't work. I need help as soon as possible! Thanks.

```
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.win32-x64-msvc.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-win32-x64-msvc' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.darwin-x64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-x64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.darwin-arm64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-arm64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-x64-musl.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-x64-gnu.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm64-musl.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm64-musl' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm64-gnu.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm64-gnu' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './zstd.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm-gnueabihf' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.android-arm64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-android-arm64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.android-arm-eabi.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-android-arm-eabi' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-x64-msvc.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-x64-msvc' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-ia32-msvc.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-ia32-msvc' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-arm64-msvc.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-arm64-msvc' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-x64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-x64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-arm64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-arm64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.freebsd-x64.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-freebsd-x64' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-musl.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-gnu.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-musl.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-musl' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-gnu.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-gnu' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm-gnueabihf' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/snappy'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/lib/mongo/index.js
./src/lib/api.js
```

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Any updates?